# Copying large files to Android device stops with an error

Tags: linux, android, usb-device

I'm trying to copy video file (~12 GiB) via USB to Android device (OnePlus 7 pro) and constantly getting an error like this:

[image: this]

or like this:

[image: this]

(libmtp error)

Small files usually transferred successfully (< 1 GiB).

Comment: What distribution and version of Linux are you using? MTP used to have bugs with files larger than 2GB, but that was years ago (https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1472789).

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint Debian Edition 4